# How can I use filters in listNetworks with dockerode?

Tags: typescript, docker, dockerode

I want to list docker networks with specific name and I've tried to use options like

```
import Docker from "dockerode";
const docker = new Docker();
const ntw =  await docker.listNetworks({
         Name:"qwerty"
  })
console.log(ntw);
```

But when I tried to run this script I got all networks so how can i get network with name "qwerty" only? Picture as follows.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5BOYF.png)

Comment: Please do not add images of text, edit your question and copy the text directly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `Array.prototype.filter`

```js
import Docker from "dockerode";
const docker = new Docker();
const ntw =  await docker.listNetworks({
         Name:"qwerty"
  })
const [qwerty] = ntw.filter(elem=>elem.Name==='qwerty')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I'm still wondering how to use configs provided in docker api (referrences in [link](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.41/#operation/NetworkList)

Comment: Try to write `Name` with lower case

Comment: I've tried but it still doesn't work. Well, thanks anyway, i've given up and turned to ntw.filter()

Answer (score 0):

```
const networks = await docker.listNetworks({
  filters: JSON.stringify({
    name: ['qwerty'],
  }),
})
```